# cmake: make_directory in built time

Tags: cmake

I have this code that runs during configuration time:

```
if (NOT EXISTS "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tmpdir/")
  file (MAKE_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tmpdir/")
  message ("Generating tmpdir directory")
endif ()
```

How do I implement the above code but in build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I implement the above code but in build time?

It depends on when you exactly need this directory. For instance if you need it before executable `foo` compiled, you can use [add_custom_target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) and [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html):

```
add_custom_target(
    make_temp
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E make_directory "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tmpdir"
    COMMENT "Create 'tmpdir'"
)

add_executable(foo ...)
add_dependencies(foo make_temp)
```