# Cross platform alternative `mkdir -p` in makefile + cmake

Tags: shell, makefile, cmake

I'm writing makefile, that works with cmake. makefile just creates the build directory and start cmake in it, if build directory is not created yet, or redirects targets to makefile created by cmake, if it already exists. I used `mkdir -p` to create a build directory, but it is not cross platform.

Is there any cross platform variant for `mkdir -p`? May be cmake provides alternative command, like it does autoconf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cmake -E make_directory` (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake.1.html)). If the parent directories are not existing, it does create all directories up the given one.

If you use it inside a CMake script itself, e.g. as pre-build step: `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory`

**References**

- [Creating a directory in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702115/creating-a-directory-in-cmake)
- [cmake: make_directory in built time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094662/cmake-make-directory-in-built-time)